# RoR - Combining multiple assets into a single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I combine multiple CSS files within app/assets/stylesheets into a single application.css.scss? According to the book I've been following, I'm suppose to reference all other stylesheets into the application.css.scss comment section. However, it didn't tell me how I can refer to each stylesheet.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I know I have to use `*= require_something` but not sure exactly how. I've created a stylesheet called  custom.css.scss and placed *=require_custom within the comment but this didn't work.

Comment: Multiple answers have been posted in response to this question. Have any of them helped? If so, it's considered both polite and helpful to upvote/accept them as correct.

Comment: Any update to this? If any of these answers helped resolve your question, you should consider accepting it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `require_tree .` directive should be sufficient to load any additional stylesheets contained within `app/assets/stylesheets`. However, static assets are always loaded when the app is spun up – have you tried restarting your server?

Answer (score 0):

`require_tree .` already requires all the separate stylesheets in the same folder or subfolders.

If you want to include some specific stylesheet (say something.css.scss), you can do:

```
*= include something
```

However if you use variables in your SASS files which you want to use across different files, the comment style includes don't work. You'd need to import each file separately:

```
@import 'something';
```

Comment: However, when I look at the page source of my webpage, I still see multiple stylesheets listed. Shouldn't I only see one if I'm including all the stylesheets into one?

Comment: I mean what's the point of including all the stylesheets into one file if I'm going to see all of them listed in my source code?

Comment: In development, you'll indeed see all the files listed separately. Under production however, all the different stylesheets listed in your application.css.scss manifest will be minimized and combined into a single file. See the asset pipeline documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html